# How to create a POST request from this ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: rest, post, http-post, esri, arcgis-server

I have a published image service from a raster dataset and now I want to replace its data with a new raster dataset using the UPDATE RASTER operation of POST request from `ArcGIS` Request API. The documentation is [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/update-raster.htm).

The item id of exisitng service is this: `5a7cac53fd40427f8e92b7d4d8461c47`

How can I construct a REST request using the above documentation and complete the task? A example would be great.